# php - Facebook redirect after login not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I checked all the Stackoverflow previous question related to this. But none of them are same like mine.
I implemented Facebook login for my website. Its working good. But the problem is after login, the page is redirecting to Facebook home instead of redirecting to my website.

My Codes are below. I did not changed much from the official documentation of Facebook developers.

login.php

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '****',
  'app_secret' => '****',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'user_likes']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.com/login-callback.php', $permissions);

echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

?>
```

login-callback.php

```
<?php

# login-callback.php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '****',
  'app_secret' => '****',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

$redirectloc = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];  
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}


if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
  header("Location:$redirectloc"); 
exit();
  // Now you can redirect to another page and use the
  // access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} elseif ($helper->getError()) {
  // The user denied the request
  exit;
}

?>
```

When I am logged in already in my Facebook account from the same browser, and trying to login from my website, its working perfectly.
i.e `header("Location:$redirectloc");`  in login-callback.php is working as expected. Its redirecting to login.php.

Now If I logout from my Facebook account from the browser, and try to login from my website, its asking for Facebook id and password which is normal.

But after entering user id and password its redirecting to the Facebook home page instead of redirecting to login.php.

Comment: Well, because the referer contains the url of facebook. What you need is to save the location in the session and then recall the old location and redirect the user back to it.

Comment: Great, I hard coded the redirect code and its working. Thanks. Now I know where is the problem. But how to redirect to the exact previous page after login?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois please post it as answer, so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes from the referer and is expected. The referer, sent by the browser, contains the URL it came from. Since you were on Facebook, the referer will contain the URL `facebook.com` (possibly more than just the domain). If you leave out the redirection to `facebook.com` (due to already logged in), the referer contains the last visited page of your site.

The solution to this problem is, before redirecting the user to Facebook, save the referer in a session and then redirect to Facebook. Then in `login-callback.php` you can read the redirect location from the session and use it for `header("Location: ...")`.